# Alexa Web Information Service how to output with php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I've signed up to the Alexa Web Information Service and downloaded the [sample php code from here](https://aws.amazon.com/code/AWIS/402).  I've followed the help file and run it in a terminal which works fine and outputs what I would expect. However, when I try and include it in a php file and output the data through a web browser I get nothing, not even an error message.

Does anyone know of any good help guides or tutorials? Or is there something simple I'm missing?

Comment: Please include some code samples from your own implementation.

Comment: I don't have any implementation code. Other than <?php include ('filename.php');?> where filename.php is the downloaded code file from AWIS.